# How to save varchar2 column in oracle using PySpark?

Tags: oracle, dataframe, pyspark, clob, varchar2

Since this [bugfix](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/40683) I'm unable to save data as varchar, only clob.

The problem is that oracle does not allow index on cblobs. I need to save ROWIDs in varchar2 columns to manage MLOG tables. My save command is:

```py
delta_mlog_df = df.select(F.col("ROW_ID"),F.explode(F.col("TRANSACTIONS")).alias("TRANSACTION_ID"))
delta_mlog_df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ) \
    .option("dbtable", ORIGIN_MLOG_HIST_TABLE) \
    .option("url", ORACLE_URL) \
    .option("user", ORACLE_USER) \
    .option("password", ORACLE_PASSWORD) \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .save()
```

The data is saved as:

```
 TRANSACTION_ID  NUMBER
 ROW_ID          CLOB
```

There is some way to force some column type when I save the data? (like to_sql dtypes for pandas?)

Comment: You could file a bug report on PySpark or else use a version from before the "bugfix".

Comment: @MT0 There is no bug report on PySpark, only PR report, with hundred PR's to be merged... I need to fix it fast.

Comment: my ugly temporary solution was:

`ALTER TABLE TBL ADD  ROW_ID varchar(100);`
`UPDATE TBL SET row_id = CAST(row_id_clob AS VARCHAR2(100));`
`ALTER TABLE TBL drop COLUMN row_id_clob;`